# Dump several processes simultaneously when one process runs on a server

Tags: windbg, remote-debugging

I have a client program that communicates via a local Windows service to a server process. These three programs are implemented by ourselves. To analyze an error situation, I'd like to take crash-dumps of all three processes at once, so that there are no inconsistencies between them. The trigger is an exception in the client.

In the testing environment, the server runs on the same machine. In that case I can attach to the processes in question using `.tlist` and `.attach`. Once the exception is thrown, all processes get suspended and I can do a `.dump` on each single dump.

Is it possible to achieve the same result if the server is running on a different machine? How?

I have tried: attaching WinDbg to the serverside process, then running a remote debugging server (`.server`), connecting to it from a new WinDbg instance on the client. But then I can't attach to local processes, since the `.tlist` and `.attach` command operate on the server instead of the client.

Comment: I was thinking about suspending and dumping multiple VM's at once wich I believe should be possible but then you have another problem to solve: How to trigger a dump of a farm on a exception in your program?!

Comment: Why not have two instances of Windbg: one to attached to the serverside process and one attached to the client side process?

Comment: @MarcSherman: I appreciate every idea. How to synchronize the 2 WinDbg instances so that the server gets suspended when an exception occurs in the client?

Comment: Launch the second instance of Windbg from the first instance's `sxe` command's `-c` or `-c2` for the client. Or would too much time have passed by the time the server gets suspended?